# Laravel / PHP displaying wrong output for for variable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Using Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.0+, mysql 5.7 I have a query that returns an array with the correct info.

**propoffice model**

```
namespace App\models\core;

class propoffice extends \App\Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'officeID';
}
```

Heres my initial query

```
  $officeList=propoffice::select('officeID','xOfficeID')
  ->orderBy('officeID','desc')
  ->take(1)
  ->get();
```

There are TONS of records but lets just look at one.  Thats why I have the take(1) for now.

```
dd($officeList)
```

I see

```
  #attributes: array:2 [▼
    "officeID" => "123"
    "xOfficeID" => "123"
  ]
  #original: array:2 [▼
    "officeID" => "123"
    "xOfficeID" => "123"
  ]
```

Running the loop

```
foreach($officeList as $the){
    echo $the->officeID;
}
```

Instead of seeing 123 - I am seeing 0 for the officeID field, but I do see 123 for xOfficeID field.

I have no javascript or jquery running changing values or anything complex going on.

There is no other code between the array and the output so it has to boil down to some laravel / php process that I'm not involved in directly.

The field in question is indeed a field name elsewhere, and the values would NOT match. I feel this is at the root, but dont know how or where to look.

EDIT:
I had my model setting the primaryKey to officeID which is varchar.  In laravel primaryKey is expected to be an integer, which slipped my mind.  So the raw data was fine, but when returning values in the output, the NON-integer values were mutated as 0 by the model

Comment: let me see if I understand, the officeID field is on another table? so you are getting this field from a function in your model?

Comment: Please can you show the code for `$officeList`

Comment: The question shows the exact data I expect to loop through or query for values.  the officeID field is being converted to zero or 1 while the other field shows as expected.  The only difference is the field name.  So I was making a stab in the dark that maybe its due to the field name in existence on a different table.

Comment: That dd shows $officeList as a model  not a collection...

Comment: Yes, it is a model.  It has nothing but a reference to the primaryKey and tablename.  No relationships at this point made.  The field in question though is indeed a field name elsewhere, and the values would NOT match.  I feel this is at the root, but dont know how or where to look.  There is no other code between the array and the output so it has to boil down to some laravel / php process that I'm not involved in directly

Comment: Why would you be looping through a model?

Comment: $the->officeID; should throw an error. Are you sure that it show you an output ? you should try like `echo $the"`in this loop, $the as a string

Comment: why, you used loop for one result?

Comment: I obtained results by querying a model and looped through it.  The output I posted is just showing you the structure and that I can successfully interact with it but the field name officeID returns 0 instead of the value I see the structure.

Comment: You guys are missing the point of the question.  I am not looping through a model or for one result.  My question has to do with why is my variable getting returned as zero or 1 instead of what I see in results??  I can loop through the results perfectly and show it all, but ONE field is converted into zero or one instead of what I actually see in the results

Comment: Well your question needs to be able to be reproduced so we can even begin to understand why that would be, but right now, it looks like you either have presented invalid pseudocode or aren't accessing the data properly.

Comment: @weekapaug please check my answer

Comment: Consider all fields display fine when looped through.  They ALL output exactly as I see in the dump, but for some unknown reason this ONE field is displayed as ZERO or 1 despite the fact that I see the real value before output.

Comment: are you displaying them with `echo $the->officeID;` in loop ?

Comment: Yes, in your scenario, think about this.  When I go $the->officeID I see 0, despite the data showing 123.  If I use $the->xOfficeID, I see 123, exactly as I should.  So this officeID field is getting some special treatment for some reason, and thats what Im trying to understand

Comment: @weekapaug generate a better mcve then.  Is it just a specific model returning a 0 for officeID or all of them?  You had earlier that officeID was from another table and now that's gone and your dd shows different so your question has had a lot of confusing/conflicting info in it.

Comment: can you take a ss about your model attributes ? because it's extremely weird.. first off all ` echo $the->officeID;` should throw an error -_-

Comment: 0 means may be false ? But still no make sense it should throw an error anyway

Comment: I thought it was possibly returning boolean value too instead of actual value, but all fields are filled so its not in reference to that.  If it is boolean, I have no idea what its checking against, or why its not just spitting out exactly what it shows as it does for other fields.  It might be trying to hook into the other table with that officeID, but I have no reference to it anywhere.  Is there a limitation to not use a key that exists in a different unrelated table?

Comment: I thought so.. can you take a screnshoot of model ? I really want to see with my own eyes.

Comment: I added my query to the top of the question, but there is nothing else to screenshot except a screen that would show 0 where you would expect to see 123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `0` because there is a conflict between your model and your table

in your model you set `officeID` as a primary key but in your table it's a varchar column. The models expect the primaryKey column to be an integer.

That gives you error. So you should either

1. Remove protected $primaryKey = 'officeID' line on your propoffice model
2. Make the field an integer if you need it be the primary key.
3. Figure out how to set your primary key to be a varchar.  (bad practice).

Comment: I am not having trouble outputting.  I am having trouble with the output matching what the results actually show.  In your above example my results would say that officeID=0, regardless of the fact the results are showing 123.  However I do see the correct data on other field names

Comment: Heres the odd part.  If I insert a dd($the) at the start of the loop, I see what to expect and its correct.  If I insert a dd($the->officeID) it showing as zero.  So something is changing during $the->officeID that doesnt happen during the dd($the); what process would be activating this behavior?

Comment: something changes because --I assume that-- $the->officeID is false (0) -- actually i should throw an error btw -- .@weekapaug can you try with `var_dump($the->officeID);` and share with me the output ?

Comment: I now see this... int(0) 0.  Its not an integer though, if thats what int(0) means.  This could help... something somewhere is expecting an integer for some reason? There are some ID's that are integers and those ARE showing.  Now to understand what part of the process is making it expect anything particular at all??

Comment: From what I recall the ways an eloquent model attribute can mutate their value are: relationships, acessors (getOfficeIDAttribute) and protected $casts.

Comment: @weekapaug nope it's boolean. and I totally lost, why you are so persistent about taking a screenshot ..

Comment: also can you share of propoffice model

Comment: this is ALL thats in the model - namespace App\models\core;

class propoffice extends \App\Model
{
   protected $primaryKey = 'officeID';
}  Oh wow, this just helped me

Comment: If I make officeID primaryKey, its EXPECTING an integer.  I need to make it a primaryKey but NON integer.  Your line of questioning helped me though.  Make your answer be that I have my primaryKey in the model set to a non integer field, and tell me how to do that and I can accept your answer!!

Comment: @weekapaug my dude if you want to make it primary key with non integer (probably varchar) it's not a good practise.. I think you should use integer - index - uqniue column for that (ı assume you want to unique column for officeID ).. If you want I can edit my answer with that way ? And don't forget to edit your queston too because this question may be help others.

Comment: I understand its bad practice, and I probably will change that field to an index vs primary key and do the increment ID for the primary.  Your main answer can just be edited to tell me this so its not buried in comments for anyone else looking.  It had to do with a laravel model expects primaryKey to be an integer by default,whereas your answer suggests syntax